# Open a new window from codebehind C# with window.open

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to open a new window i have tried window.open

```
string url = "../Printticket.aspx";
       string fullURL = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'height=600,width=1000,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,titlebar=no' );";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", fullURL, true);
```

when i tried this from the samefolder which the print ticket is theior iam getting it right but when i tried it from the different folder iam not getting popup

Comment: Well, the problem is in your url, don't you think? `../` references one level up, so if you don't have that document one level up from where you are calling this, it won't show.

Comment: What's the difference between the two scenarios?  When the JavaScript executes in the browser for the non-working scenario, what happens?  What request does it make to the server and what is the response?

Comment: printticket.aspx is one level up the this file

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the site relative url:

```
string url = ResolveUrl("~/yourfolder/Printticket.aspx");
```

I would always try to use site relative urls in asp.net so that urls work across your app, no matter what folder your pages are in.

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = "~/Printticket.aspx";
```

Your url path plus your form name like ~/SomeFolder//Printticket.aspx

Comment: please provide name of the folder where your form exists